# p:dataTable does not display emptyMessage value on filtering

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have `h:outputText` and `p:selectOneMenu` filters in `p:dataTable` columns.
When filtering, it does not display the `emptyMessage` value if no records are returned. Rather, it displays the first page with the default result set, and the `paginator` changes to `(1 of 1)`.

How to correct this?
(JSF 2.2, PrimeFaces 6.0)

Comment: Tried PF 6.1? Checked the releasenotes? Issuelist? And JSF-2.2 is not something you actually use, it is an API version. Mojarra 2.2.x or MyFaces 2.2.x are what you actually use.

Comment: Oh and before I forget... please read [ask], especially the [mcve] part

Comment: Please provide the XHTML code you have written for this `p:datatable`.